# Chrome Extension context menu does not persist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

In my background.js file I have the following code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (info) {
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function () {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            "title": "Blog this image",
            "contexts": ["image"],
            "id": "contextimagelink",
            "onclick": onImageClickedHandler
        }, function () { });
    });
});
```

The idea is that any time the extension is installed or updated to remove any existing context menus I've set up before and install only the one.

The problem is that every time the extension is *updated through the store*, the context menus are removed, but not reinstalled.  I can't figure out a way to debug this, or why it is happening at all.  It does not happen ever during development, only when the extension is updated after I've published an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the context menu at the [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled) and [`chrome.runtime.onStartup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onStartup) events.

For sample code, take a look at https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/blob/master/src/bg-contextmenu.js
In this extension, context menus are an optional feature, whose state is controlled through a preference persisted via the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API.
Also, there's an [open Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264963) with the `onInstalled` event in incognito mode. I've solved this problem in https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/blob/master/src/incognito-events.js

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mcobficgnfpkmfggdmlbllhemkbaloop - version 0.64 should be up in 30 min or so.

Comment: @wtfsven I haven't installed your extension, only viewed it with the [Chrome Extension Source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin). When I viewed your background.js (v0.63), I saw `targetUrlPatterns: ["*/post/*"],`. This is an **invalid [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)**. You would have known that there's an error if you checked the result of [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError) in the callback of `.create`.

Comment: That's odd.  It works fine when the extension is installed initially and the context menus are actually there.

Comment: @wtfsven Your v0.64 is up but the mentioned bug is still not fixed. However, the context menu on images does work, at least on my machine (Chromium 31.0.1650.63).

Comment: v0.65 is up with your fix and it seems to work.  Thanks for the help.